# Testing Backbone Model using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

It is the first time I write a javascript test for a Backbone Model.
Looking in the web resource there are not so many items about this subject.
I found this one, [Testing Backbone applications with Jasmine and Sinon](http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/25/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-2.html), which is pretty old (mars 2001).

Anyway I would like to know:
1) there are other resource more update about this subject
2) the text I wrote (1) is fine or can be improved.

---

(1)

```
describe('User model', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        this.model = new User();
        this.collection = new UserCollection();
    });

    describe('When creating models', function () {
        it('the url should be equal at corresponding api_get_users value', function () {
            expect(this.model.url()).toEqual(backendRouter.generate('api_get_users'));
        });

        describe('when no id is set', function () {
            it('should return the collection URL', function () {
                expect(this.model.url()).toEqual(this.collection.url);
            });

        });
        describe('when id is set', function () {
            it('should return the collection URL and id', function () {
                this.model.set({id: 1});
                expect(this.model.url()).toEqual(this.collection.url + '/' + this.model.get('id'));
            });
        });

    });

    describe('when fetching model from server', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            this.model.set({id: 1});
            this.fixture = this.fixtures.Users.valid;
            this.fixtureResponse = this.fixture.response.users[0];
            this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
            this.server.respondWith(
                'GET',
                backendRouter.generate('api_get_users') + '/' + this.model.get('id'),
                JSON.stringify(this.fixtureResponse)
            );
        });

        afterEach(function () {
            this.server.restore();
        });

        it('should make the correct request', function () {
            this.model.fetch();
            expect(this.server.requests.length).toEqual(1);
            expect(this.server.requests[0].method).toEqual('GET');
            expect(this.server.requests[0].url).toEqual(this.model.url());
        });

        it('should the response not change', function () {
            this.model.fetch();
            this.server.respond();
            expect(this.fixtureResponse).toEqual(this.model.attributes);
        });

        it('should exhibit mandatory attributes', function () {
            expect(this.model.get('id')).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: While an interesting topic and question, the 2nd part of your question is probably more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe SO is not the right place for code reviews, take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Some notes any way:

```
describe('when id is set', function () {
    it('should return the collection URL and id', function () {
        this.model.set({id: 1});
        expect(this.model.url()).toEqual(this.collection.url + '/' + this.model.get('id'));
    });
});
```

You should test for `this.collection.url + '/' + 1`, cause this is what you wanna send to the server. Maybe you will change the `get` function of your model latterly, the test will pass but the outcome is not what you expect.

```
it('should make the correct request', function () {
        this.model.fetch();
        expect(this.server.requests.length).toEqual(1);
        expect(this.server.requests[0].method).toEqual('GET');
        expect(this.server.requests[0].url).toEqual(this.model.url());
    });
```

This test is pointless cause you just test Backbone functionality, that is hopefully tested by the Backbone people. Same for the other 2 tests. As long as you do not magic stuff in your model it makes no sense to test the default Backbone functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody covers jasmine testing better than [Justin Searls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108159/justin-searls):

https://speakerdeck.com/u/searls/p/confidencejs

is one example but check out his other presentations as well and his github repo for [jasmine-given](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-given)

Comment: +1 thanks for your reference. Actually in my question I am asking something more specific: Testing Backbone Model. and in jasmine-given repository I cannot find what I am looking for.